# Creating a default style for text-danger when it's applied on a panel using Less

Tags: html, css, less

So I'm new to using Less files to improve my CSS, I currently have a panel.less file which contains all the CSS for creating panels on my page.

I'm looking to somehow make it so that whenever the text-danger class is applied to the panel `div`, it changes the `font-color` to white rather than red.

```
.panel-variant(@border; @heading-text-color; @heading-bg-color; @heading-border) 
{
    border-color: @border;

    & > .panel-heading {
        color: @heading-text-color;
        background-color: @heading-bg-color;
        border-color: @heading-border;

        + .panel-collapse > .panel-body {
            border-top-color: @border;
        }

        .badge {
            color: @heading-bg-color;
            background-color: @heading-text-color;
        }
    }

    & > .panel-body {
        color: @gray-dark;

        + .text-danger {
            color: @heading-text-color;
        }
    }

    & > .panel-footer {
        + .panel-collapse > .panel-body {
            border-bottom-color: @border;
        }
    }
}
```

Above is the code I use in the Less file, What am I doing wrong?

The HTML would look like this though if that helps:

```
<div class="panel panel-body text-danger"> ERROR! </div>
```

Comment: Your HTML markup? Whose font color should be changed when the `div` inside has text-danger class? The panel or the body or just the element which has the class?

Comment: Why do you use + sign before `.text-danger`? This selector means that it will target all `'.text-danger` elements that are placed immediately after `.panel-body`.

Comment: I want to change the text-danger styling from showing red text to instead show white text while inside panel-body.

Comment: Ok, so it is *inside* panel-body and not a sibling of panel body is it?

Comment: I'm not sure, they html would look like this though if that helps    <div class="panel panel-body text-danger">
        ERROR!
    </div>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the HTML given in the comments, all the three classes are applied to the same element and not to different siblings or child elements. Hence your Less code should be modified as below:

**Modified Less:** (I've ommitted the other parts to keep it simple)

```
&.panel-body {
  color: #777;
  &.text-danger {
    color: @heading-text-color;
  }
}

/* mixin call */
.panel{ 
  .panel-variant(1px; #fff; #0f0; #00f);
}
```

**Compiled CSS Output:**

```
.panel.panel-body.text-danger {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

---

Your original Less code had descendant selector (for `.panel-body`) and adjacent sibling selector (`+`) for the `.text-danger` and would work only when the markup is as follows:

The adjacent sibling selector (`+`) works only when the markup is like this:

```
<div class='panel'>
  <div class='panel-heading'>Heading</div>
  <div class='panel-body'>Body</div>
  <div class='text-danger'>Some alert text</div>
</div>
```